# Why Are Transaction commit/rollback even Required

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

I am trying to understand Transactions in MySQL I have been at it for 3 days and I am not getting it

By my general understanding transactions are used inside a stored procedure, If an error occurs in between (a transaction and commit statement) then the data is not committed meaning changes are not made in the main server

I am calling the stored procedures in the database itself, so if i Deliberately enter in the wrong data type it throws an exception/error , I have used 3 variants of syntax in the stored procedure

```
BEGIN 
// CODE TO BE EXEC   ---------------->   (used this as i read the "BEGIN" keyword is just an alias for transaction)
END;
```

---

```
BEGIN 
START TRANSACTION ;  ---------------->   (applied this because everyone recommended to add tranasction)
// CODE TO BE EXEC
COMMIT;
END;
```

---

```
BEGIN 
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
    RESIGNAL;
END;

START TRANSACTION ;
// CODE TO BE EXEC     -------->   (rollback to be executed when an exception is thrown but i dint think this worked)
COMMIT;
END;
```

I have made sure to insert a wrong data type input **that comes after execution of some statements before it**, now naturally that throws an error for a wrong data type, but the changes are not made to the database for the statements that were executed lines before the invalid statement was executed **for all the 3 types of code**, so why do we use rollback if this gets the job done, the only change i saw was the auto incrementing id column in a table skipped values and that applied for all 3 code syntax, even the 3rd code which has rollback in it, I have also added autocommit = 0 before start transaction and acutcommit = 1 after the commit statement but it didn't work, I didn't include that syntax as i read that starting a transaction is same as autocommit = 0, Explicitly locking the tables was also suggested but it I didn't understand the basics so I didn't even know how to apply that

**Basically Why are rollbacks used when MySQL throws an error and no changes are applied , and why is the second variant of the syntax listed above even necessary if the first one does the same thing**

*Using MySQL 8.0.22 > WPF/C# > Dapper*

Comment: Suppose you want to undo a partial transaction even if no SQL error occurred?  The "error" could be something that SQL would not consider an error (like when a traditional program runs w/o throwing an exception but doesn't proceed the correct result).

Comment: @ScottHunter Can you not just do an update for that ?

Comment: Not all actions are reversible (short of a rollback).